# Attempted read from closed stream on Response Body

Tags: java, spring, http, httpresponse

I have come across many blogs that answers a way to read response body like below

```
Response response = e.getResponse();
            String body;
            try {
                Reader reader = response.body().asReader();
                body = CharStreams.toString(reader);
                log.info("body " + body);
                if (reader != null)
                    reader.close();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                log.error("error reading body ", ex);
            }
```

But I am getting `java.io.IOException: Attempted read from closed stream.` What is it throwing the error

EDIT:
I was passing "Response" to the ApiException and setting it there. Removed that and used response body as String instead to fix the issue.

Comment: a) From a `Reader` you have to `read` b) Are you trying to read the body multiple times?

Comment: "Steam is closed" means you may read stream somewhere. 
In this case, the root reason is toString() of respsonse. 
Those function reads the steam and ensure closed the stream.
That means you can not display response in debug model in IDE. 
So dot no log response before read it.